# Minimum requirements for a phone for android support

Tags: android, android-compatibility

Can someone tell me what is the minimum requirement a phone should obey so that an android OS can be installed over it.

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Android Compatibility Definition Document (CDD)](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-2.2-cdd.pdf) may help you.